# Вывод времени, форматирование числа

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем проблема?
Имеется код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Таймеры</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
<script language = 'javascript'>
    var id = setInterval ("startTime()",1000);
    var minutes = 0;
    var seconds = -1;   
    function startTime() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds==10) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes < 60) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
        }
        else if (minutes==10) {
        minutes = 0;}
        if (seconds < 60) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

</script>
  <b>Время на сайте: <span id="time"></span></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Задача стоит следующая 
    Выведите время, проведённое пользователем на странице в формате: mm:ss. Например, 01:15 или 02:00. То есть первые 2 цифры – это минуты, а вторые 2 цифры – это секунды. Каждую секунду время должно увеличиваться.

Примечание: Обратите внимание, что если число минут или секунд меньше 10, то должен быть добавлен ведущий 0, то есть чтобы не было 01:5, а было 01:05.

Время выводится, но "0" перед минутами появляется только после 60 секунд первых.

Comment: @manai пожалуйста, формулируйте заголовок вопроса более приближённо к тексту. "Javascript вопрос", согласно правилам форума, - плохой заголовок, поскольку не содержит никакой информации относительно имеющейся проблемы. Я предлагаю сменить его на "Вывести время, проведённое пользователем на странице, в заданном формате".

Comment: @manai перестаньте откатывать заголовок вопроса  на бессмысленный.

Answer (score 4):

Во первых, не нужно делать seconds++ - interval не обязательно выполняется раз в секунду.

во вторых, в кавычках параметр setInterval писать не нужно, в третьих у вас тут все слишком заморочено с алгоритмом.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var id = setInterval(TickTime, 1000); //запускаем таймер
    var startTime = new Date(); //начальное время в миллисекундах
    var output = document.getElementById("time"); //элемент в который будем выводить
    function TickTime() {
        var passed = parseInt((new Date() - startTime) / 1000,0); //сколько секунд прошло с момента старта
        hours = ('0' //добавим строку 0 в начале
                 +parseInt(passed / 3600,0))
                .slice(-2), //возьмем последнии два символа из строки
        minutes = ('0'+parseInt(
            passed % 3600/60 //остаток от деления(сколько секунд прошло в текущем часе) поделим на 60
            ,0)).slice(-2),
        seconds = ('0'+parseInt(passed % 60,0)).slice(-2);
        output.innerHTML = hours+':'+minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KjYL7/

Answer (score 0):

У вас условия minutes < 60, проверяется если seconds==10 см. [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/dK975/1/)

Comment: откройте ссылку, которую я вам сбросил и посмотрите когда происходит alert - затем подумайте!

Answer (score -1):

Вариантик без постоянного вызова Date() http://jsfiddle.net/avengerweb/KjYL7/1/

Comment: я же сказал почему так нельзя, или не понятно ? 

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KjYL7/2/

перейдите на другой таб в браузере на некоторое время, потом вернитесь, посмотрите на разницу во времени. у меня получилось в хроме - 30 секунд погрешности за полторы минуты.